# how to solve the problem of "import gradio could not be resolved"

Tags: python, gradio

[importing api from gradio quickstart but in terminal it's showing a prblem of "import gradio could not be resolved"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85ZjI.jpg)

how to make complier accept gradio

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to resolve the error so far?

Answer (score 1):

firstly make sure that you have installed the library using the following command.

```
pip install gradio
```

The solution is to select the python3 interpreter inside the bin/ folder of the python installed

[image: vs code python interpreter selector]

click on the enter interpreter path here and choose the python3 inside the bin it will get the import error solved.

in my case i was using a venv so i'm selecting the python3 so that the pylint in the vscode will now the packages.

[image: python3 selection]

Comment: Hello Thanks for the ans but what I have done is created a venv and selected python interpreter but still the compiler is not accepting the gradio

Comment: Have u tried pointing to python instead python3 ? have tried reinstalling the package